# 'Undefined const' ERROR while trying to display const alongwith API output data

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to display a CONST countrycode along with API output data but REACT says const is undefined?
Question:1: Is there another way I could display the constant ??
Question 2: How can i take this const as a user input and use it in API as well as display with other info on the page?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    maxWidth: 1000,
    margin: "0 auto",
    marginTop: 50,
  },
  paper: {
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
    textAlign: "center",
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
  },
  title: {
    color: "#3f51b5",
    textTransform: "uppercase", //could be slowing down?
  },
}));

export default function CountryPanel() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const countryCode = "ca";
  const url =
    "https://api.thevirustracker.com/free-api?countryTotal=" + countryCode;
 
    const [globalData, setGlobalData] = useState({});
    
  useEffect(() => {
    getData(url);

    async function getData(url) {
      const response = await fetch(url);
      let data = await response.json(); // convert to json
      const countrycode = data.countrydata[0].info.code;
      const countryname = data.countrydata[0].info.title;
      const srcurl = data.countrydata[0].info.source;
      console.log(countrycode, countryname, srcurl, "constants");
      delete data.countrydata[0].info;
  
      setGlobalData(data.countrydata[0]);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>

<h1> Country Code: {countrydata[0].info.code}</h1> // ERROR not defined ??       
????

<Grid container spacing={3}>
        {Object.keys(globalData).map((key, ind) => {
          return (
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={4} key={ind}>
    ..
  </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might happen that first time when component renders, at that time `countrydata` does not contain any data and you are trying to access `countrydata[0].info.code`.
So if `countrydata` itself contains no data then you cannot access its properties.
To avoid this you should add condition as below-

```
<h1> Country Code: {countrydata[0] && countrydata[0].info && countrydata[0].info.code}</h1>
```

It should avoid the error of accessing the properties of undefined. Because `logical AND` prevents that.
See more - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
<h1> Country Code: {globalData.info.code}</h1>
```